# Using share intent in android for instagram

Tags: android-intent

I want to share some image to instagram in my app.
With facebook, twister... I know, I can do it by using Share Itent
But wit instagram I don't know.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 for Question Quality - Stack Overflow is not your Research Assist, please refer to [What Can I Ask Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what is appropriate to ask on Stack Overflow. Please provide specific questions, examples about what have you tried, or what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution by using share intent

*This is sample*

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/jpeg");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
             Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/jusgramm.jpg"));
                //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,data);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image Via"),SHARE_PIC_REQUEST);
```