# share a photo in instagram

Tags: android, instagram, file-sharing

i'm developping an app  and i'm trying to share a picture in Instagram .

i'm using the code below :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/jpeg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+savedPhotoPath));//savedPhotoPath is the path of my picture stored somewhere in the sdcard
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
```

the problem is that the instagramm is launched with the home activity,( i want to have the activity of share that picture to be launched ).

i've tried to put the extras like this :

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, new File(savedPhotoPath));
```

and

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(savedPhotoPath));
```

with the same result , always , the home activity of instagram application is launched .

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Regards,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297930/using-share-intent-in-android-for-instagram

Comment: thanks @jnr , i've just founded that post and i've figured it out , it's just a simple error of adding a slash in the path :)

Comment: Are you also able to send your app name along with your image So that other can Recognize that this content is send via a different app Not Instagram directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just a stupid error i've made, i've added a slash on the `file:///` path , and it will concat with savedPhotoPath and it will become 4 slashes , so the correct way to put extras is :

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+savedPhotoPath));// it will give : file:///sdcard/...
```

Comment: Are you also able to send your app name along with your image So that other can Recognize that this content is send via a different app Not Instagram directly