# Share intent for instagram in Android

Tags: android, instagram

Actually I want to share image in Instagram through intent.

[I found this solution for images saved on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497543/share-a-photo-in-instagram) but I want to do same for image on site (link).

I tried with

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent
            .putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.alliswell.biz/images/products/art/alliswell_signs/yellowB.jpg"));
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But it's not working.

### Edit

When I start above intent it opens my installed Instagram application and it immediately finish Instagram and toast message comes "unable to download file"

Actually it does not parse link and image respectively. What should be issue?

Comment: define *not working*. Any error message ?

Comment: "unable to download file". message comes from instagram app

Comment: Same issue here. Trying to figure out whether the image exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

You should use local path to file

For example: "file:///path/to/file/image.png".

Note, that it is very important to include "file" in the path, without this part it also can show the same toast.

Comment: still getting same issue in photo sharing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download file from that url. you may refer this code for downloading image from url:

```
String imageUrl = "Your_Image_Url";

    if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.equals("")) {

        String fileName = generateFileNameFromUrl(imageUrl);

        String imageLocalPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"Your_App_Name"+ fileName;

        if (!new File(imageLocalPath).exists()) {

        ImageDownloadModel imageDownloadModel = new ImageDownloadModel();

        imageDownloadModel.setImageLocalPath(imageLocalPath);

        imageDownloadModel.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

        imageDownloadModels.add(imageDownloadModel);

        }
        ImageLoadAsynkTask imageLoadAsynkTask = new ImageLoadAsynkTask(new ImageDownloadDelegate(), imageDownloadModels, albumDir, activity);
        imageLoadAsynkTask.execute();
```

and then use uri for that image for sharing it on instagram:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + imageLocalPath));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
```