# How to send a photo to Instagram using my Android app?

Tags: android, share, photo, instagram

My app takes photos and I want to share it on Instagram.

My app save the image in this directory

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/tubagram");
```

Now I'm trying to get the last picture I took to share in Instagram using this code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
final String[] p1 = new String[] {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};
Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");

if (c1.moveToFirst() ) {

    Log.i("Test", "last picture (" + c1.getString(0) + ") taken on: " + new Date(c1.getLong(1)));
}

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/tubagram/" + c1.getString(0)));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

c1.close();

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I receive a Toast with this error message "Unable to download file".
This Toast is sent by Instagram.

I tried to use this link example - [share a photo in instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497543/share-a-photo-in-instagram) - but didn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I add this line after the camera.takePicture.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

This line does a "refresh" and after the phone recognizes the news photos saved on your phone.

And I made some changes on my method

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");                 

final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
final String[] p1 = new String[] {
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
};
Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");

if (c1.moveToFirst() ) {
    Log.i("Test", "last picture (" + c1.getString(1) + ") taken on: " + new Date(c1.getLong(2)));
}

Log.i("Image path", "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Tubagram/"  + c1.getString(1) + ".png");

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Tubagram/" + c1.getString(1)+".png"));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

c1.close();

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

And with this another method I verify if the Instagram is installed on the phone

```
private boolean verifyInstagram(){
    boolean installed = false;

    try {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.instagram.android", 0);
        installed = true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        installed = false;
    }
        return installed;
    }
```

Comment: Please, try to always use english methods and variables, is better for everyone to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Are you also able to send your app name along with your image So that other can Recognize that this content is send via a different app 
Not Instagram directly

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your button click listener it will redirect you into app and make sure your device have installed Instagram app.

```
String type = "image/*";
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageview.getDrawingCache();
Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(bmap);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
if (Utils.isPackageExisted(this,"com.instagram.android")) {
 share.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
}
share.setType(type);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
```

Comment: what is `getLocalBitmapUri`?

Comment: **getLocalBitmapUri** is the function that gives uri from Bitmap image

Comment: here is the code:
.
 

`public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
     Uri bmpUri = null;
     try {
       File file =  new 
       File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 
       "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
File mFileImagePath = " /storage/emulated/0/Image Editor/Media/FilterImages/Image_Editor_1547816365839.jpg  ";  // Just example you use file URL

private boolean checkAppInstall(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        //Error
    }

    return false;
}


private void shareInstagram(File mFileImagePath) {
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
    if (intent != null) {
        Intent mIntentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String mStrExtension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(mFileImagePath).toString());
        String mStrMimeType = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(mStrExtension);
        if (mStrExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("") || mStrMimeType == null) {
            // if there is no extension or there is no definite mimetype, still try to open the file
            mIntentShare.setType("text*//*");
        } else {
            mIntentShare.setType(mStrMimeType);
        }
        mIntentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(mFileImagePath));
        mIntentShare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        mIntentShare.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
        startActivity(mIntentShare);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Instagram have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This code works for me and will work on all Android devices.