# Share image and caption to instagram via Android app

Tags: android, instagram

I want to share my application image and application title to instagram via my android application.

I have used below code for the same

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(SearchCategory.this, imagebitmap));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT TO SHARE IN INSTAGRAM");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "YOUR TEXT HERE");
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But this doesn't work.

`The instagram  application version is` **7.11.0**.

Please help for the same.

Comment: Please make clearly question, post log or anything about this.

Comment: I can able to send only image, but subject ,text and title is not there, In instagram i can see only image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864138/how-to-send-a-photo-to-instagram-using-my-android-app

Comment: This link is for sending image, but my question is to send image with caption. I am able to send image. problem is image with caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since August 2015 that you can't.

*Beginning today, the iOS Hooks and Android Intents **will stop accepting captions passed** by third party apps.
(...) **Instagram will ignore the caption text**. To create a caption for a photo or video shared by a third party app, users will have to enter a caption manually, the same way they already do when sharing content using the Instagram native apps.*

http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing