# Directly Share an Image to Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, WhatsApp ect

Tags: facebook, android-studio, instagram, share, whatsapp

In my app, there have multiple buttons (FB share, Twitter Share, Insta Share, etc) to share an image to social media. also have a `More` button to show all sharing feature lists of the user devices to share user choice. I have successfully worked The `More` button to show all sharing options (here I use *FileProvider*). But the other buttons (without this "More" button) I couldn't work. For example, when the user clicks on the `FB share` button then should be directly open Facebook app and the image load on ***Create a post*** (where written "*What's your mind*") option for sharing the Image to Facebook. I have set the FB package to intent. but it just opens the Facebook app (does nothing, just open FB app homepage). But on the `More` button there have a FB option `News feed`, if click on this then it's successfully working to send the image to ***Create a post*** option.

Can anyone give a solution to share The image on any social media? I have seen Facebook SDK. but I think there has a more easy solution which I don't know. Because there have so many social media (though I implemented only 4).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864138/how-to-send-a-photo-to-instagram-using-my-android-app

Comment: Bro! I tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know if this works for you but I'd give it a try. Using this, media can be shared with other apps: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem from my senior bro. I just added a line *intent.setPackage(packageId)* on my old share code. then it worked. The full process is given below.

**Step 1.**
Add these lines inside the application block of *AndroidManifest.xml*.

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

**Step 2.**
Create a *file_path.xml* file inside *res/xml* folder (if xml folder not available, create it). past this code in *file_path.xml* file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
     <external-files-path name="my_images" path="/" />

     <!--For Share-->
     <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
     <cache-path name="cache_files" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

**Step 3.**
Create a ShareUtils.kt object file and past this code.

```
package com.example.riz1.utils

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.liilab.photo_editor.BuildConfig
import java.io.File

object ShareUtils {
  interface FileUriCreator { val uri: Uri }

  fun shareImage(context: Context, imagePath: String, packageId: String){

    if (packageId!=AppConstants.DEFAULT_PACKAGE_ID && context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageId) == null) {
        context.customToast("Please first install the app")
        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageId")
        ))
    }else{
        val fileUriCreator = object : FileUriCreator {
            override val uri: Uri get() = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                     BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", File(imagePath))
        }
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            if (packageId!=AppConstants.DEFAULT_PACKAGE_ID) intent.setPackage(packageId)
            intent.type = "image/jpeg"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUriCreator.uri)
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"))
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            context.customToast("Please first install the app")
            context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageId")
            ))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now just call *ShareUtils.shareimage(context,ImagePath, packageId)*. If you want to open default share list just remove *intent.setPackage(packageId)* and can *packageId* would be null.